# Trying to navigate XML file using nokogiri and xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

I have an xml file which is a download from: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

What I'm trying to do is navigate through the currencies, so that I can save them in my database.

I have:

```
open('app/assets/forex/eurofxref-daily.xml', 'wb') do |file|
      file << open('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml').read
 end

then 

doc = File.open("app/assets/forex/eurofxref-daily.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
```

I am having a hard time accessing the nodes I'm interested in to extract currencies and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Nokogiri, but [from this tutorial](https://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html), it looks like you can apply the following XPath: `/*/e:Cubes/e:Cube/e:Cube` to select all of the `Cube` elements.

From there, you can iterate over each of the `Cube` elements, and select their `@currency` and `@rate` attributes:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"))
@doc.xpath('/*/e:Cubes/e:Cube/e:Cube', 'e' => 'ttp://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref').each do |node|
  # do stuff
  currency = node.attr('currency')
  rate = node.attr('rate')      
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to figure it out using a very similar approach to yours. I used: doc.xpath("//xmlns:Cube/xmlns:Cube/xmlns:Cube")